# How to know if a WSASend() operation has been completed without calling GetQueuedCompletionStatus()?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock, iocp

When calling `WSASend()`, I have to pass it a `WSAOVERLAPPED` instance, and I cannot re-use this `WSAOVERLAPPED` instance until the previous `WSASend()` operation has been completed (i.e. when a completion packet has been placed in the completion port).

Is there a way I can know if the `WSASend()` operation has been completed without calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`?

Comment: `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` only works if you are using an I/O Completion Port.  Are you?  To simply check the current status of the operation, you can wait on the event object you put in the `WSAOVERLAPPED`, or you can call `WSAGetOverlappedResult()` with `fWait` set to FALSE.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes I am using IOCP.

Comment: You're not allowed to reuse the `WSAOVERLAPPED` instance until you've dequeued the IOCP by calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`.  Whether the underlying operation has completed or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Steve -- if you do have a completion port, you may introduce a race condition with such check, depending of course on what you do after the packet is dequeued from the port. You may end up checking the result of a wrong operation (if OVERLAPPED is reused) or dereferencing invalid memory if it freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`WSAGetOverlappedResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the `WSASend` progression:

```
/* size bytes to send */
WSASend(Sock, &aBuf, 1, NULL, 0, &overlap, NULL);

/* warning no test for error cases */
DWORD dummy;
DWORD sent;   
do 
{
    /* Ask for the sending progression without waiting */
    WSAGetOverlappedResult(Sock, &SendOverlapped, &sent, FALSE, &dummy);
    /* to prevent too much CPU usage */
    Sleep(15);
} while (size != sent);
```

Comment: But the documentation says the following: *"If another form of notification was selected, the usage of the hEvent parameter of the WSAOVERLAPPED structure is different, and setting fWait to TRUE causes unpredictable results"*, and I am using another form of notification (which is a completion port).

Comment: Yes, that's why I set it to FALSE

Answer (score 2):

you need bind own socket to system created IOCP as result when operation finished your callback will be called automatic. you have 2 options here:

- use [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) - this will be work from Windows
  XP (really even from win2000)
- use [`CreateThreadpoolIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx) - work from Windows Vista

after you create socket by

```
SOCKET socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 0, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED)
```

you need call `BindIoCompletionCallback((HANDLE)socket, *,0)` or `CreateThreadpoolIo((HANDLE)socket, *, 0, 0);`

and all. you not need call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` or wait at all